# How to disable Wuala automatic program updates?

Tags: automatic-update, wuala

Wuala seems to automatically update itself. This is a severe security problem because the company can push an update to all or some users stealing their passwords. This invalidates the security promise that only the user can access his files thanks to client-side encryption.

How can I disable Wuala automatic update?